# Portfolio return through beta

Tags: portfolio-management, returns, beta, asset

Considering the beta value of the three assets in my portfolio simulation and the weights of the assets, i have computed the beta of the portfolio itself.
How can i calculate the expected return of the portfolio?

(I have also the expected return for each of the three assets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected return of the portfolio is just the weighted sum of the expected returns of the assets, i.e.
$$
R_P = w_1\cdot R_1  + w_2\cdot R_2 + w_3\cdot R_3,
$$
where $w_1, w_2, w_3$ are the porfolio weights and $R_1, R_2, R_3$ are the expected returns for the assets.